# Python pdf2image: hide consoles

Tags: python, pdf, poppler

I'm using `pdf2image` which uses `poppler` to convert PDF to images. However, when you use it in Python it opens a new console every time to convert a PDF. Is there a way to hide this console?

```
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
  if file_name.endswith('.pdf'):
    pages = convert_from_path(path + file_name, thread_count=4)
    idx = 1
    for page in pages:
      page.save(file_name + '-page-' + str(idx) + '.jpg', 'JPEG')
      idx += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, but you might not like it. You have to modify the convert_from_path function a bit. Currently the function looks like:

```
import os
import re
import tempfile
import uuid

from io import BytesIO
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from PIL import Image

def convert_from_path(pdf_path, dpi=200, output_folder=None, first_page=None, last_page=None, fmt='ppm', thread_count=1, userpw=None):   
    page_count = __page_count(pdf_path, userpw)

    if thread_count < 1:
        thread_count = 1

    if first_page is None:
        first_page = 1

    if last_page is None or last_page > page_count:
        last_page = page_count

    # Recalculate page count based on first and last page
    page_count = last_page - first_page + 1

    if thread_count > page_count:
        thread_count = page_count

    reminder = page_count % thread_count
    current_page = first_page
    processes = []
    for _ in range(thread_count):
        # A unique identifier for our files if the directory is not empty
        uid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        # Get the number of pages the thread will be processing
        thread_page_count = page_count // thread_count + int(reminder > 0)
        # Build the command accordingly
        args, parse_buffer_func = __build_command(['pdftoppm', '-r', str(dpi), pdf_path], output_folder, current_page, current_page + thread_page_count - 1, fmt, uid, userpw)
        # Update page values
        current_page = current_page + thread_page_count
        reminder -= int(reminder > 0)
        # Spawn the process and save its uuid
        processes.append((uid, Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)))

    images = []
    for uid, proc in processes:
        data, _ = proc.communicate()

        if output_folder is not None:
            images += __load_from_output_folder(output_folder, uid)
        else:
            images += parse_buffer_func(data)

    return images
```

The line we are interested in is:

```
processes.append((uid, Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)))
```

We need to explicitly tell Popen not to show the console windows like so:

```
startupinfo=None
if platform_name == 'Windows':
  # this startupinfo structure prevents a console window from popping up on Windows
  startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
  startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
processes.append((uid, Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo)))
```

Some versions of python 2.7 might need to use:

```
 startupinfo=None
    if platform_name == 'Windows':
      # this startupinfo structure prevents a console window from popping up on Windows
      startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
      startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    processes.append((uid, Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional information:

In order to hide the console window completely when running from a compiled executable in Windows, need to patch three functions in pdf2img.py in which Popen is called:

1. convert_from_path()
2. pdfinfo_from_path()
3. _get_poppler_version()

For example, from:

Popen(command, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

To:

Popen(command, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, creationflags=0x08000000)

I am using Python 3.8 in Windows, whereas 0x08000000 is the new subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW flag in Python 3.7+

Answer (score -1):

currently the code comes by default:

```
# Spawn the process and save its uuid
    startupinfo=None
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        # this startupinfo structure prevents a console window from popping up on Windows
        startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
        startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    processes.append(
        (thread_output_file, Popen(args, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, startupinfo=startupinfo))
    )
```

I've tried many things and the console keeps popping up

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does this mean you have the same issue, and the answers here don't solve it? You're not getting help this way: you should ask a new question, linking this one and explaining what is not working for you

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, after researching and testing I have to say that currently convert_from_path function is configured so that no console window appears, the console that I see coming and going is because of poppler, that is, python calls convert_from_path and the actions that the function performs are not seen due to the hidden console, however among all the operations it does, one is to call "pdftoppm.exe", so if you have a loop or convert a lot of PDF's to image you will see a cmd console opening and closing quickly.

I Have Python 3.9+